# How to add 3D effect on Column Chart and Bar chart in ng-google-chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, 3d, angular-chart

I am creating charts using ng-google-chart.js

Here is my html code.

```
<div google-chart  chart="colChartObject"</div>
```

In js I have written like this

```
            $scope.colChartObject = {};

            $scope.colChartObject.type = "ColumnChart";

            $scope.colChartObject.data = $scope.data;

            $scope.colChartObject.options = {
                title: $scope.title,
                isStacked: false,
                titleTextStyle: { color: '#000000', fontName: 'Open Sans', fontSize: 16, bold: true, italic: false },
                height: 250,
                is3D:true,
                colors: [{ color: '#FF0000', darker: '#680000' }, { color: 'cyan', darker: 'deepskyblue' }]
            };
```

where $scope.data is defined as below

```
        $scope.data = {

        "cols": [
            {
                "id": "level0-id",
                "label": "level0",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "id": "level1-id",
                "label": "level1",
                "type": "number"
            },
            {
                "id": "level2-id",
                "label": "level2",
                "type": "number"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "1-2 DAYS"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 42,
                        "f": "42 items level 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 67,
                        "f": "67 items level 2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "3-5 DAYS"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 68,
                        "f": "63 items level 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 89,
                        "f": "89 items level 2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "6+ DAYS"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 57,
                        "f": "57 items level 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": 123,
                        "f": "123 items level 2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here in $scope.colChartObject.options I have mentioned is3D:true

```
    $scope.colChartObject.options{
         is3D:true
         }
```

but there is no 3D effect on output chart .

How to add 3D effect on chart ?
[image]

If I am using

```
    $scope.colChartObject.type = "PieChart";
```

and

```
    is3D:true
```

then I get 3d effect on pic chart .[image]

But why there is no 3D effect for 'ColumnChart' and 'BarChart' ?

I want o/p something like this [image]

I can change the data,colors etc . I am interested to know how to add 3D effect .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

google's pie chart is the only one that supports --> `is3D`

you can check the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options) for each chart type to see which options are supported...

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat. Any idea how to create 3D column chart ?